# How to stop URL updation or Direct pasting of URL in ASP.net Applicaton

Tags: c#, asp.net

When user do change the URL I want him to show any error page or somthing else that can
 be suitable.
 I don't want to access the different pages via typing the URL,User should go
 through proper channel e.g. Click links and buttons on the page.

Comment: what do you mean? Can you illustrate with scenario ?

Comment: I strongly advise not to try to limit user in a way described as it would cause a major usability problems and user frustration.  Can you explain why do you think you need such requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Try to do like as mentioned here: http://p2p.wrox.com/html-code-clinic/23573-how-do-disable-menu-bar-address-bar-browser.html

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow.

A user typing a url in the browser is not the only way for a user to access a page. A user can always write a script that fetches the page. As long as the page is accessible by a url, there will be a means to fetch that page outside of your "proper channels".

Given the above, if you elaborate on your question, explain why you have to do this, maybe we can come up with an alternative method to achieve that end result.

If I take your question at face value, you could make all the pages except the home page only accessible via POST. You would have to modify all your buttons and links to instead make a form submission to the desired url. The point being, if the user simply types the url in the address bar, the browser will issue a GET request and your server will reject it. You can style the error pages to inform the user to instead use the "proper channels".